# BERT Masked Language Model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I've started dissecting the **BERT** paper by google (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) and stumbled upon few points that I don't understand.

My questions is about Masked Language Model.

First, we mask 15% of the tokens and the learning task is to predict those tokens (it's seems like a long way to converge).

But we don't simple mask it with [MASK] but 10% of the time: we replace it with a random token. **But why?**

Moreover, in another 10% we keep the token unchanged

> The purpose of this is to bias therepresentation  towards  the  actual
>   observed word.

This citation confused me completely, in 80% cases we actually mask it, how 10% will help us to preserve a bias.

I would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: https://medium.com/dissecting-bert/dissecting-bert-part2-335ff2ed9c73#2d9f This should help answer your question